# A measure for P(R)

Tags: measure-theory

We know that -unfortunately- Lebesgue measure cannot measure all the subsets for $\mathbb{R}$ for example ([Vitali Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set))

My question is : can we build a measure for all the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, that extends Lebesgue Measure ? And if so, can we explicitly define it ?

Thank you for your answer

Comment: Of course, the counting measure is well known, although it is a bit childish. Even the Dirac measure, which can be shifted to a different origin.

Comment: What properties do you want from this measure?

Comment: Or define $\mu(E)=0$ for every $E$. Or say $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ but $\mu(E)=\infty$ for every $E\ne\emptyset$. To get an interesting question you need to specify what conditions you want the measure to satisfy.

Comment: somehow to be a generalization of Lebesgue measure : 
1 - for each interval [a,b] its measure is b-a
2 - defined for all subsets of $\mathbb(R)$

Comment: By the way, without the axiom of choice, if you choose the right axioms, every set can be measurable for the Lebesgue measure,

Comment: If I recall correctly, and note that I may well _not_ be recalling correctly, there _does_ exist an extension of Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$ that's defined for all subsets of $\Bbb R$. Of course it cannot be translation-invariant, otherwise the traditional construction of a non-measurable set would show that the domain cannot be the entire power set.

Comment: Reference : "Real-measurable cardinal."   Lebesgue measure can be extended to a countably additive measure on  $P(R)$ iff there exists a real-measurable cardinal. The existence of such a cardinal cannot be proven from $ZFC$ (unless $1=0$ is also  a theorem of $ZFC.$)

Comment: Speaking of the axiom of choice, I believe that Vitali set is based on it. If we choose to omit this axiom. Does that mean that Vitali set doesn't 'exist' anymore ?

Comment: Are you talking about the outer lebesque measure  ? 
Since what does "extending" mean in your case? Since $\mu^{*}|_{\Sigma}$ Needs to be a lebesque measure

Comment: @user254665 That's doubtless the result I was almost recalling. Wikipedia says that there exists such an extension of Lebesgue measure if and only if there exists a real-measurable cardinal $\le c$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal#Real-valued_measurable